# How to rename a SharePoint folder using Microsoft Flow

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am running a Microsoft Flow and it says it ran successfully but I am trying to rename a folder and the folder isn't renamed.

I have searched websites for a few days now and there isn't much available for flows that rename folders.  All I could find is a flow step 'Send an HTTP request to SharePoint' so I have tried this in various forms.

1. A folder is copied using a Flow step and named Folder123
2. Send an HTTP request to SharePoint
   Site Address: ............
   Method: POST
   URI: /_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('............. Name' 
   Headers
     Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
     X-HTTP-Method: MERGE
     If-Match: *
     Body: {'Name' : 'Test123'}

There is no error message, the message is: The flow ran successfully.
The expected result is that the folder that is created should be named 'Test123'.
The actual result is that the folder is still named Folder123, so it wasn't renamed.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one thing in your body which is **OData** type value.

Follow below steps, it works.

1. First, get the folder's *OData* type with a **GET** request. 
   [Rest call to get folder oData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQBe.png)
2. Design your rest code as per image
   [Send HTTP Request to sharepoint - Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feUXZ.png)

So finally your body call looks like below. Your OData type would be depend on your library configuration.

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem' },'Title': 'Patel', 'FileLeafRef': 'Patel'}
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

Comment: Thank you Hiren, I thought I must be missing something.  Now I can't get the GET to work, I get an error "Bad Gateway".  My Send HTTP request look like this Method: GET, Uri:........................./ListItemAllFields, If-Match: *, content-type: application/json;odata=verbose, accept: application/json;odata=verbose.  I must be missing something here.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  In the GET, I currently have this:{
  "If-Match": "*",
  "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
} and I am getting the following error      "message": "The object specified does not belong to a list.\r\nclientRequestId: a3f80c2c-c856-4702-9016-8a89cddac676\r\nserviceRequestId: 3193e99e-3042-0000-2e7d-096d1f52c9e1",  Is my library configured incorrectly for this?  Can anyone please help with how I can fix this?  Thank you.